# Friends who are "invited" vs. "added" on a FB closed group page

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups, friends

I started a closed group page on FB. As I did, I thought I invited friends from my own FB page to be a part of this group as the prompts allowed me to do. As the page evolved, I noticed that many of my friends were not participating, while others were. I wanted to know if those who were not participating were not doing so because they "declined" the invitation, so I looked at their status.

The status of some says "invited" by me, while the status of others says "joined."

- Does it mean that those who were invited are still not aware of the group, or have they opted not to get notifications, or have they opted out?
- What options are they given when they are invited?